# Detect Combination Key Event

Tags: c#, winforms, events, keyboard

I would like to perform a key event detection in textbox. The keys should be a combination of Ctrl+K, is there any best way to do it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In KeyDown event of TextBox, use:

```
  if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.K) {
  //Your code here
  }
```