# Catching MAJ + TAB click on textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I have to catch the event when I pressed on <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd> in `TextBox` to write some code. It is possible to do that? I tried with that test on `KeyUp` event :

```
    private void txtJustifTampon_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
     if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab && Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.ShiftKey)
        {
            //do stuff
        }            
    }
```

Comment: What is `MAJ` ?

Comment: Shift or ShiftKey

Comment: Try that code in `KeyDown`event

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect Combination Key Event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107492/detect-combination-key-event)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I determine in KeyDown that Shift + Tab was pressed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11150930/how-can-i-determine-in-keydown-that-shift-tab-was-pressed)

Comment: @Pikoh : i tried the code on the KeyDown event, but it doesn't work

Comment: @C4u : it's not the same, i tried their solution and it doesn't work

Comment: See the duplicate proposed by @Sinatr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the possible ways out is to use [PreviewKeyDown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.previewkeydown(v=vs.90).aspx) instead of `KeyUp` since

> Some key presses, such as the **TAB**, RETURN, ESC, and arrow keys, are
>   typically ignored by some controls because they are not considered
>   input key presses

```
private void txtJustifTampon_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e) {
  // If Shift + Tab pressed (i.e. Tab with Shift modifier) 
  if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab && e.Modifiers == Keys.Shift) {
    //TODO: put relevant code here (do stuff)
  }
}
```

Please, notice that we should use `Keys.Shift` (not `Keys.ShiftKey`) as the *modifier* and we should apply modifier to the event argument (`e.Modifiers`)